# For loop only executes once, raising a number to another number

Tags: c++

New to programming/coding, and couldn't get why my code doesn't work.

It's supposed to show you the result of raising a number to another number. But it only ends up looping once.

Example of error:

```
Input an integer: 3

Raise integer to what number: 4

3 raised to 4 is 9
```

My code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int raiseToPow(int nNum1, int *nResult) {
  *nResult = nNum1 * nNum1;
}

int main() {
  int nNum1, nNum2, nResult, i;

  printf("Input an integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &nNum1);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Raise integer to what number: ");
  scanf("%d", &nNum2);
  printf("\n");
    
  for (i = 0; i < nNum2; i++) {
    raiseToPow(nNum1, &nResult);
  }
  printf("%d raised to %d is %d", nNum1, nNum2, nResult);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `3^4` does not equal `9`.

Comment: `raiseToPow` says it will return a value but it does not. Not sure what the purpose of the loop is. The function arguments do not change based on it so `raiseToPow` always performs the same operation. Call it once or 20 times you're still going to get the same thing which in the example given is `3 * 3`.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

you should initialize nResult by 1 because your variable doesn't have anything inside. Also, replace *nResult = nNum1 * nNum1 by *nResult = *nResult * nNum1

Answer (score 0):

It's looping the right number of times, you just need to put the print inside the loop. Also you should add a newline to the end of your print.

```
for(i = 0; i < nNum2; i++)
{
    raiseToPow(nNum1, &nResult);
    printf("%d raised to %d is %d\n", nNum1, nNum2, nResult);
}
```